# how to backup raw- / kvm-device directly over the network

Tags: ansible, backup, block-device

I have setup some VMs on a Hypervisor. Each of which is using a raw LVM Volume as disk. This way I can use LVM Snapshots to prepare a backup. Up to this point that is working and the only missing piece of the puzzle boils down to:

How can/should I do something like this with ansible:

```
dd bs=16M if=/dev/h-vg/vm-dev | ssh root@serverB "dd bs=16M of=/path/to/backup.img"
```

I know that I can first use `dd` to create the image and than `ansible.builtin.fetch` to pull it down. But than I would need three times as much hard disk space as the volume I want to backup, since I need space for the snapshot and additional space for the image.

##### Update With regards to the Comments

I know that using the `shell` module is an option (as always) but I want to make sure that there isn't any other more »ansibleish« way to do that, to avoid all the downsides of using the `shell` module.
Piping data over ssh is some sort of general tool, but since ansible is managing all the »to and fro« I am curious if the is an ansible way to stream data like that.

Comment: Is your Use Case about connecting from a Ansible Control Node to a Remote Node ServerA and transfer the data to a Remote Node ServerB?

Comment: Did you simply try to launch your command in a `shell` task? There is no reason for it not to succeed as long as you have a correct ssh key configured on server A to access server B

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question straight: There is no way in ansible to do something like the above without the usage of the `shell` module. This comes with all the downsides when using the `shell` module what shouldn't be used unless there is absolutely no other way around.

However, since my objective here was: »backing up KVM VMs« I found two alternative ways.

1. Mount a network volume (nfs, etc.) and use `dd … of=/path/to/network/drive/…` This way the data will be copied over the network without piping it over `ssh`
2. [Libvirt offers the ability to create backups](https://libvirt.org/formatbackup.html) (full and incremental) in »pull mode«. Going that way libvirt creates a »network block device (NBD)« which exposes a network block device, which in turn can be read from the target system.